# vuforia multiple imagen targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a very big data base of images and I want that Vuforia can detect all of them.

Do I have to place all the data base images one by one in the target image prefab separately?

Is there a better way?

Is there another prefab called multiple targets, but is used to detect objects in 3D, I think.

Thanks